# How to add my own domain to Meteor Galaxy?

Tags: meteor, dns

Sorry for my English. I have an application on the Meteor. For deploy I use Galaxy, but I have a problem with domain. It seems, like Galaxy doesn't provide any dns address that I can add to domain. I also try to change CNAME record according to Galaxy docs, but there is error.

Comment: Can you give us more information about what error you get?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this dns address from the picture below.
[image]

You can read more about **Adding additional custom domains in Meteor Galaxy** - [here](http://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/custom-domains.html#add-domain).